# Present Progressive Instead of Present Simple

Tags: word-usage, present-tense, present-progressive

I've had much discussion with many people about a certain use of Present Progressive tense instead of Present Simple tense. I perfectly well know that Present Simple speaks of habitual actions, events, and facts. What about Present Progressive? It is a rather young tense in English and I really intend to understand it's usage in the way of describing habitual actions, events, and facts. I'll give you some examples:

> 1. I eat every day!
> 2. I am eating every day!

It's perfectly clear that Present Simple here is more appropriate. It describes the fact that you consume food every single day. But,
"I am eating every day," can mean that you are sick and tired of it, yet you have to do it or else you'll die. I can mean that it's a fact that exists now. What if in 3 years time you'll become a robot and you won't have to eat, supposingly? It means that it's not a fact any more, if we look into the future, and it's happening now starting from the past and will be like that until it changes. 
Can't it also mean that you like the process of eating and you enjoy it, and that is why you said that in Present Progressive?

For instance:

> 1. At seven in the morning, every morning, I'm waking up and then I am brushing my teeth. I love it so much.

What if some day you won't wake up at seven in the morning? But you do, don't you?

Another example:

> 1. The Moon is going round Earth!

You'll say, "Hey, man. The Moon goes round Earth," and you will be right. 
But in an uncertain amount of centuries it won't. The Moon may probably not even exist. It can happen any moment! So we are saying that it is going round Earth. Though it's a fact.

Another good example of poetic English:

> 1. The sun is rising in the east!
> 2. The sun rises in the east due to grammar rules.

My choice would be the Present Progressive. It's a fact but not an everlasting one. theoretically nothing is everlasting - timeless.

Here's more:

> 1. I'm seeing you every day!
> 2. I'm having coffee at 9am every day.

They all mean that you are in the process but this process occurs regularly (every day).

By the way:

> 1. I'm thinking you should go there!

It's not an every day action, yet most people say that it's incorrect, why? can't I be thinking at the moment? I don't always think, feel, see, understand and e.t.c.

Here's more:

> 1. The teacher is explaining simple rules and I'm understanding him, then he starts explaining difficult rules and I am no longer understanding him.
> 2. Every day at 8:15am I'm going to work.

I'm in the process of going to work, not that I start this event at exactly 8:15am, but this occurs every day.

Or for example:

> 1. Somebody is doing a massage and asks the person, "Are you liking it?"

How come this is incorrect? Why ask, "Do you like it?" 
I'm really not understanding this!

Another example:

> 1. It is snowing every winter.
> 2. It snows every winter.

Can't there be a winter when there is no snow? Anyway, I can give many examples. I think these will be more than enough for now!

Comment: Could you format that wall of text a little bit please? To me, "I'm eating every day" sounds like you're putting "every day" in your mouth and swallowing it.

Comment: You are assuming that the present progressive can be used for repetitive and habitual activities or actions that are conducted on a regular basis, but you misunderstood. "What do you do for exercise?" "I run everyday" vs "What are you doing now?" "I am running now." As @MorganFR commented, please take one example and ask one question. Your question reads like rant than a question. I am voting to close your question as too broad.

Comment: Okay, let's say we use "walk" instead of "eat".

Comment: Same argument could be made, you could be "walking every day" like you "walk a dog", "every day" being the dog. Eihter way, gramatically it is not correct to use Present Progressive Instead of Present Simple in this manner.

Comment: Okay. "The dog is barking all night, every night." Doesn't that seem right to you?

Comment: @SovereignSun No, it does not. I'm not sure where you're from, but I'm guessing India, as IndE habitually overuses the progressive aspect relative to other, native speaking dialects (BrE, AmE, AusE, etc). Here's the best paper I've found so far on the topic: [*Overuse of the Progressive Aspect in Indian English*, Silke Schubert, Universität Konstanz, October 2002](https://kops.uni-konstanz.de/bitstream/handle/123456789/3793/Schubert_exam.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: I'm from Russia. I've double checked myself before I posted. I've looked this up in Oxford's books, BBC, books by Raymond Murphy, and books by Michael Swan. Everywhere I see the very same thing. In some cases you can and in others you can not. I hear native speakers use present progressive quite often in some cases instead of present simple. Maybe it works only for spoken English?

Comment: This is just the way English works. There are leeway sometimes given due to popular constructs. One example that comes to mind is stative verbs being used in continuous form, like the Mc Donalds slogan "I'm lovin' it", but I have not heard of such a claim as yours from reliable sources.

Comment: @DanBron Nice information. That reminds me of "Mind your language" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_Your_Language

Comment: @MorganFR Well, I have and this still bothers me. Theoretically thinking I understand that progressive tense can be used in such a way. I've had this example not long a time ago: "Aren't you afraid for your flowers?" - No, my neighbors are watering them every evening!

Comment: @DanBron By the way, I think that, "Are you wanting a cup of coffee?" isn't that bad an example! Maybe because it is close to Russian? Are you wanting it at this very moment when I'm asking?  Are you understanding me? - Yes, so far! But I might not be understanding you later on!

Comment: @SovereignSun Hahaha! I never noticed that correspondence to Russian usage before. That's funny. And now I have to go watch Mind Your Language on YouTube. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @DanBron Glad to be of good use to you! I does have a correspondence. in Russian one sentence can have several meaning and several sentences can have one meaning. That's normal, but English has it too so that is why it is of so much interest to me! I've stumbled upon old English and there are many interesting oldish-es that are now in process of being reborn. Usage of prepositions in the end of a sentence for instance!

Comment: The progressive is not a tense, it's an aspect.

Comment: @BillJ Excuse me, but sources tell us that it is another name of the Present Continuous tense. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_continuous  https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/present-progressive  http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_progressive.htm

Comment: Then the sources are wrong! English has only two tenses. Here's a link to a more scholarly resource: [link](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/tense.htm).

Comment: @BillJ So Present Progressive is a Present tense and a Progressive aspect of it that is also known as the Continuous aspect?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The terms "progressive" and "continuous" are synonymous here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to refer to the present but instead make predictions, forecasts, predictions based on evidence etc... you might want to look further into future tenses

Comment: What future tenses?

Answer (score -1):

When I use the present progressive, and the way I have understood it from past classroom experience, is that it is better used with additional or other information.  If I were to say, "Everyday, I eat breakfast", it would suffice to make it known that breakfast is an everyday occurrence.  If I were to use the progressive, it would be with *further explanation* -- "Everyday, I am eating breakfast *because of my new diet."*  One more: I see him today.  I am seeing him today once I get home.  That's my thought on it.

Comment: I don't agree with your first sentence, but the second one has nothing to do with the OP's problem, as it is not a habit, but just a one time thing in the future.

Comment: Here's a good one. You may be right on this one. Context means a lot! What about this? It's new to use present progressive in order to speak of an early event that you've started to occasionally do. I'm running every day. - Would mean that you've started, not too long ago, to run every day and it's happening in this period of time.

Comment: "Every day, I eat dairy for breakfast, because of my new diet" and "Every day, I have been eating dairy for breakfast, because of my new diet" are correct, what you are using here is some sort of combination of those, but it is not right.

Comment: @M. C. Jones "I am seeing him today once I get home" doesn't express repetitive or habitual action or activity. It expresses a future aspect in the same way as "I will see him today once I get home".

Comment: Comments are for constructive feedback to the author -- in this case, M. C. Jones. Please limit comments to this purpose.

Comment: @Rathony I've double checked this 'I am seeing him today once I get home.'. Thanks to you and Jones M.C. I clearly understand this aspect of using Present Continuous!